# Implement LinkedIn sign in on Flutter with custom scopes

Tags: flutter, dart, linkedin-api

I need to authenticate my users against LinkedIn on flutter.

Currently I am using this flutter package [linkedin_login](https://pub.dev/packages/linkedin_login) to achieve that.

It works great but there is no way to specify custom scopes which is mandatory to my app.

Here is a sample of my code:

```dart
LinkedInUserWidget(
  redirectUrl: redirectUrl,
  clientId: clientId,
  clientSecret: clientSecret,
  onGetUserProfile: (UserSucceededAction linkedInUser) {
    print('Access token ${linkedInUser.user.token.accessToken}');
    print('First name: ${linkedInUser.user.firstName.localized.label}');
    print('Last name: ${linkedInUser.user.lastName.localized.label}');
  },
  onError: (UserFailedAction e) {
    print('Error: ${e.toString()}');
  },
)
```

Is there another way to specify custom scopes?